# I have two images which is use for pin or unpin data in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-image, flutter-design

I have two images in flutter which is use for pin and unpin the data in list view so my program is that when i click on pin image than unpin image should be hide and when i click unpin image than pin image should hide. so how to implement this thing in flutter.

here is my demo code

```
class PinUnpinData extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PinUnpinDataState createState() => _PinUnpinDataState();
}

class _PinUnpinDataState extends State<PinUnpinData> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(
          "Pin-Unpin",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  
                },
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/images/pin.png",
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                )),
            InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/images/unpin.png",
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a local variable to keep the track of `pinned` state. Then update the state of that variable on tap of the button using the `setState()` method. Also, for showing the relevant image, just check the value of the`pinned` variable and show the relevant image, if it's true then show the unpin image else pin image.

```
class _PinUnpinDataState extends State<PinUnpinData> {

  bool pinned = false; // to keep track if it's pinned or not

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(
          "Pin-Unpin",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                pinned = pinned ? false : true; // check if pinned is true, if its true then set it false and voice versa
              });
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Image.asset(
                pinned
                    ? "assets/images/unpin.png" //show this image when it's pinned
                    : "assets/images/pin.png", // show this image when it not pinned
                height: 20,
                width: 20,
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how do i use toastflutter to show pin and unpin in this code

Comment: Call the toast method with your message in the ``onTap: () { ... }`` method. Also, mark my answer if it helped you achieve what you were looking for. :)